How to print out ip address of domain names in a file using bash script
I have been trying to write a code that would check if a file contains domain names and if it does would print out the domain names using bash script
here is my code:
is_valid_domain() {
    local domain="$1"
    if host "$domain" &> /dev/null; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}


if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
    filename="$1"
    # Check if the file exists
    if [ ! -f "$filename" ]; then
        echo "Error: File '$filename' not found."
        exit 1
    fi
    
    #if the file exists
    #Process each domain in the file
    while IFS= read -r domain_name;  do
        if  is_valid_domain "$domain_name"; then
echo -e "Domain name: $domain_name\nIP Address: $(host "$domain_name" | awk '/has address/ {print $4}')"
        else
            echo "No domain names found"
        fi
    done < "$filename"


When I run my script with a file that contains domain names as the first command line parameter it just pauses action and does not continue is there anything I am doing wrong?

if I add a trailing fi and run against a file with the contents www.google.com \n abc.def.ghi.jkl I get Domain name: www.google.com \n IP Address: 142.250.190.100 \n No domain names found; if I run against an empty file the script returns immediately (with no output generated); net result: the script works (for me); I'd recommend adding some debugging to figure out where the script is hanging; would also help if you were to provide us with a sample file (2-3 sample domains) that your script hangs on

See How can I debug a Bash script?.


...pauses action and does not continue...

I suspect that it's hanging in host because you've fed it a domain that takes a long time to check. You could override the default timeout time by using the -W <seconds> option:
is_valid_domain() {
    local domain="$1"
    host -W 1 "$domain" > /dev/null
}

